# The best approach building a proper json string

Tags: json

I am wondering what would be the best way of building json string?

I have one product that might have different variations and each variation might have different price additions or none:

```
color: black, +$5 
color: white, +$0 
size: L, +$1 
size: XL, +$4
big bada boom: No, $-4
and so fourth
```

what structure would you suggest assuming that any given attribute (color,size, etc.) is not defined anywhere and needs to be parsed on the fly?

Do you think something like this makes sense?

```
{
    "variations": {
        "Color": [
            {
                "id": "1",
                "name_definition": "black",
                "price": 1
            },
            {
                "id": "2",
                "name_definition": "white",
                "price": 0
            },
            {
                "id": "3",
                "name_definition": "Green",
                "price": 5.95
            }
        ],

        "Size": [
            {
                "id": "1",
                "name_definition": "30",
                "price": 21
            },
            {
                "id": "2",
                "name_definition": "15",
                "price": 4
            },
            {
                "id": "3",
                "name_definition": "10",
                "price": 0
            }
        ]        
    }
}
```

Comment: Unless you have the order defined elsewhere, you probably want an array rather than an object to list the different variations, so you can control in which order they are displayed. Other than that, the topic is overly broad, there are dozens of ways to approach this, with more or less flexibility (absolute prices, relative prices, relative prices in percentages, prices per variation, price per combination...).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to probably achieve something like you have mentioned could be done like below:

```
{

    "products": [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "defaultColor": "examplecolor",
        "defaultPrice": 5,
        "currencySelected": "$",
        "variations": [
            {
                "variationType": "Color",
                "variationItem": "Black",
                "variationPrice": 1,
                "variationEffectType": "Add"
            }, 
            {
                "variationType": "Size",
                "variationItem": 30,
                "variationPrice": 21,
                "variationEffectType": "Add"
            }

        ]

    }
   ]

}
```

This way for each product and its variations you only have to access a single object in products array and is easy to comprehend as well.And also few pieces of advice,use camel casing and avoid caps in the keys first letter.